# Distance between icon and text in the Button

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a button defined in the XML shown below:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_menu_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_menu_height"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/logo_menu_margins"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_blue"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:paddingStart="6dp"
    android:text="Options"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_menu_text"
    android:id="@+id/buttonOptions"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

How to increase distance between icon (set with drawableStart) and text? Text alignment is set to left. paddingStart is set to 6dp, but it applies to icon only, not the text.

Is it possible to set it with XML file?

I know I can do this using LinearLayout - containing both ImageView and TextView, but I am trying to limit nesting of the views.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`android:drawablePadding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding) attribute.

Comment: Damn, so simple. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: In Material is not working, for Material3 use app:iconPadding

Answer (score 3):

[app:iconPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIconPadding(int)) is used to determine the space between icon and text in MaterialButton